# Stylized earnings curve and fill in between them

Tags: tikz-pgf

It's been so many days that I'm trying to create by the same way the curves of the figure below.

My code so far:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{ucs} 
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{caption}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,patterns,pgfplots.fillbetween}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \draw[->, very thick] (0,0) -- (7,0) node[pos=0.5,below,rotate=0]{Ηλικία};
  \draw[->, very thick] (0,0) -- (0,7) node[pos=0.5,above,rotate=90]{Εισόδημα} ;
\draw[brown, -, thick] (1,0) node[below]{18}--(1,.8); 
\draw[brown, thick] (1,.8) to[out=90,in=180] (6,3.5) node[below]{\footnotesize \footnotesize \begin{tabular}{c}Απόφοιτος\\ β' βάθμιας Εκπαίδευσης\end{tabular} };
\draw[blue, thick, -] (2,0) node[below] {22}--(2,2.3);
\draw[blue, thick] (2,2.3) to[out=90,in=180] (6,6.8) node[below]{\footnotesize \footnotesize \begin{tabular}{c}Απόφοιτος\\ γ' βάθμιας Εκπαίδευσης\end{tabular} };
\draw[dotted] (6,6.8) -- (6,0) node[below]{67};


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

and what I would like to have
[image: age-earnings]

The parts that I'm struggling with are pointed out with the yellow line:
[image]

Comment: What part are you struggling with?

Comment: You're close, but there are a bunch of things that are different from the screenshot. I'm not sure which differences are intentional and which ones are the part you want to change. So, as Jake says, what part is giving you trouble?

Comment: Thanks for the update! Have you tried changing the values `out=90` to, say, `out=30` for costs and `out=60` for benefits? By tweaking these values (angles) you can change the shape of the curve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values of the keys `out` and `in` are the angles of the curve's tangent line relative to the positive x-axis at the start and end of the path segment, respectively.

Since you have in both the blue and the brown line the setting `from=90`, these paths start with a vertical tangent. Based on your yellow highlighting, it seems like this is not desired. You can adjust the `from=<angle>` value for each curve to change the shape of the curve: I've chosen `45` and `80` here, but feel free to change these as desired.

Another useful key for path shaping is called `looseness`, which has a default value of `1`. If, even after adjusting the angles, you don't like the shape of the curve, you can set `looseness` to some value other than 1 to change the shape further.

A few other notes about your code:

- If you add `align=center` (or `left` or `right` as desired), you can use `\\` inside the node text directly without needing a nested `tabular` environment.
- Writing `\footnotesize` a second time has no effect: just once would be sufficient for your code. However, since I removed the `tabular` in my code below, I have used TikZ's `font` key like this: `font=\footnotesize` to put the whole node text in one font size.
- Adding `-` for no arrows on a path is unnecessary (unless you need to override some other arrow setting that's in-scope).
- Where you have

  ```
  \draw[blue, thick, -] (2,0) node[below] {22}--(2,2.3);
  \draw[blue, thick] (2,2.3) to[out=90,in=180] (6,6.8) node[below] {...};
  ```

  it might be better to put these into a single path, like this:

  ```
  \draw[blue, thick] (2,0) node[below] {22} -- (2,2.3) to[out=80,in=180] (6,6.8)
    node[below,font=\footnotesize]{Απόφοιτος\\ γ' βάθμιας Εκπαίδευσης};
  ```

  This avoids needing to repeat the styling options (`blue,thick`) and also avoids repetition of the coordinate (2,2.3). It also does line joining at the intersection point, avoiding unsightly gaps (though you would not have seen them with `from=90`, they do show up with other angles).

Here's your code after I've changed the above-mentioned items:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[align=center] % <-- removes the need for tabulars - could be put here or in individual node options
  \draw[->, very thick] (0,0) -- (7,0) node[pos=0.5,below,rotate=0]{Ηλικία};
  \draw[->, very thick] (0,0) -- (0,7) node[pos=0.5,above,rotate=90]{Εισόδημα};
  \draw[brown, thick] (1,0) node[below] {18} -- (1,.8) to[out=45,in=180] (6,3.5)
    node[below,font=\footnotesize]{Απόφοιτος\\ β' βάθμιας Εκπαίδευσης};
  \draw[blue, thick] (2,0) node[below] {22} -- (2,2.3) to[out=80,in=180] (6,6.8)
    node[below,font=\footnotesize]{Απόφοιτος\\ γ' βάθμιας Εκπαίδευσης};
  \draw[dotted] (6,6.8) -- (6,0) node[below]{67};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the resultant output:

[image]

And here's a short example showing the effect of the `looseness` key. A value of `0` results in a straight line between the start and end point. A value of `1` results in a quarter-circle arc (if `to` and `from` are 90° apart). Values greater than `1` loosen the curve even further, as shown in the code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \l in {0,0.25,...,3} {%
    \draw (0,0) to[out=90,in=180,looseness=\l] 
      node[inner sep=1pt,pos=0.5,above,sloped,/pgf/number format/precision=3]
        {\pgfmathprintnumber{\l}} ++(5,5);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here's the output, with the current `looseness` setting displayed along the upper portion of each curve:

[image]

Thanks to a comment from Manuel, I realized you actually want to fill between the two curves. :-) You were on the right track with loading `pgfplots` and then `\usetikzlibrary{intersections,pgfplots.fillbetween}`. The standard usage is for use in `pgfplots`' `axis` environment: we have to use a slightly different approach when just using plain TikZ; that is

```
\tikzfillbetween[of=<path1> and <path2>]{<fill style>}
```

where the paths are named when drawn with `name path=<path1>`. In the code below, I put the fill on a `background` layer so it does not cover up the text or axis lines. I also added `split,every even segment/.style={...}` so that the fill region is split into two parts: this allows to specify a different color/style on each side of the curves' intersection point.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,pgfplots.fillbetween}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[align=center] % <-- removes the need for tabulars
  \draw[->, very thick] (0,0) -- (7,0) node[pos=0.5,below,rotate=0]{Ηλικία};
  \draw[->, very thick] (0,0) -- (0,7) node[pos=0.5,above,rotate=90]{Εισόδημα};
  \draw[brown,thick,name path=brown] (1,0) node[below] {18} -- (1,.8) to[out=45,in=180] (6,3.5)
    node[below,font=\footnotesize]{Απόφοιτος\\ β' βάθμιας Εκπαίδευσης};
  \draw[blue,thick,name path=blue] (2,0) node[below] {22} -- (2,2.3) to[out=80,in=180] (6,6.8)
    node[below,font=\footnotesize]{Απόφοιτος\\ γ' βάθμιας Εκπαίδευσης};
  \draw[dotted] (6,6.8) -- (6,0) node[below]{67};
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
  \tikzfillbetween[of=brown and blue,split,every even segment/.style={blue!50}]{green!50};
  \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here's the final result:

[image]

Comment: The question talks about “filling between”; while the image doesn't seem to need that, may be it's nice to know how one would fill (wether with a color or a pattern).

Comment: @Manuel thanks, you're right: I totally overlooked that filling is mentioned in the question title. I'm adding it now. Thanks again!